# Disable Certain Grid Column

Tags: xaml

I was wondering if it's possible to make a case or an if statement or a trigger of some sort within the XAML? My goal is to make the column header with the name ID `Isvisible = false` My columns are autogenerated which makes it a bit more tough. If I can help with making the column visibility please.

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding AllQueries, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

AllQueries is very dynamic, the columns changes based on certain actions but here is a sample.

```
AllQueries = (from z in ctx.Projects
              join y in ctx.ProjectScopes on z.ProjectScope_Id equals y.Id
              where (z.StartDate <= StartDateTo && z.EndDate >= EndDateTo && y.Value == "Community Development")
              select new {Id = z.Id, z.Created, z.EndDate, z.ProjectName }).ToList();
```

I would like to display Created, EndDate and ProjectName. I cannot remove ID because it plays a roll on my double click action.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to explicitly set in the `XAML` inside the Column Template to disable a certain `Column`.

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding AllQueries, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
 <!-- GridView's Column Template 
    <telerik:Column IsEnabled="False"> -- I'm not sure what is the exact control name for `Telerik's RadGridView Column` and if it requires setting binding to know what field it will map in the column.
   -->
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

**UPDATE**

It can be similar to this

```
<DataGrid Name="dealerList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding DealerList}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="30"  Binding="{DealerId}" IsEnabled="False" />                        
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{DealerName}" />                       
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you give me the control using regular controls? and i'll find the rest please.

Comment: This won't quite work, because the queries are very dynamic. I can't specify the headers because they differ from query to query

Comment: For example one query could have just Id, name, date. Another is Id Subject and date.

Comment: That's fine, disregard the `Header` property that was just an example. What I'm showing is an answer similar to your question on how to disable certain grid columns. I just don't know what controls telerik uses but the concept should be the same.

Comment: The concept can't be the same, :s I cannot specify Columns OR headers. They are DYNAMIC. think of it like this, you will allow every vehicle to park, BUT a blue one. You don't know how many types of cars there will be(amount of types is columns)

Comment: Okay, which one in your DYNAMIC is the blue one? Give me more context on which column you want to disable?